# htop shows multiple process for Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse

I have just started the move from windows to linux (RedHat 5) to do development.  I was given a VM (configured with 2 processors) which has a older version of Eclipse (Helios) and JDK 1.6_22.

I noticed - using htop - that when I start up Eclipse and run it that there are several processes (11) that are present and stay through out the day.

The question is - is that normal, should their be that many processes activated for eclipse.    They all have different PIDs but running the same command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a clear answer for this [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7799667). In short,  it's showing threads that have been spawned by the main process.